# Share login credentials between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, google-smartlockpasswords

Is there any API to share user's login/password data between iOS app and Android app? Given I'm the owner/developer of both apps.

For Android there is Google's Smart Lock for Passwords. And for iOS there is Apple's Shared Web Credentials. These allow sharing credentials between web app and native app on the corresponding mobile platform. But I can't find any evidence that these technologies allow or not sharing between different native platforms.

If not, maybe there is another solution?

Comment: You can use common Api for login and logout for both apps. You create that Api in language of your choice c#.net , php as well as Ruby.Use that api to login in your app.

Comment: You can also use facebook or gmail or twitter login in your app so that credentials remain same in both app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly not what you want to hear but I would say this is not expected behaviour, nor is it secure. The expected behaviour would be have your user login to both platforms, after which their credentials are saved on both platforms.

There are alternative solutions however, such as `OAuth`. You can have user's authenticate via Facebook, Instagram or the many other popular platforms. That way the user does not need to enter a password, or remember one at all.

Another alternative could be to do instant sign in via an email link. I've seen that get popular recently. A user enters their email/username, they receive an email with a button to confirm the sign in.

Comment: Not sure if it's less secure than how Smart Lock or any other Password Manager work. Could you clarify it a little bit? Not forcing the user to reenter credentials when switching to alternative platform is actualy interesting feature to business.

Comment: @mekarthedev Well if you want to send credentials over an API your going to have to store the users password unencrypted no? Just sending it over an API can be insecure if done incorrectly. If it's an access token how can you guarantee it's for that user? It's an interesting idea but it hasn't been done unless you use a platform agnostic solution such as OAuth. A user can do it themselves (taking a password from your iCloud keychain and storing in another pw manager), but you won't have that access.

Comment: I've just had a thought about this, after seeing another application do it, you can have the user confirm they want to setup a new device, with the current device they are logged in with. Then they can scan a QR code to get the required data to finish the sign in process. It requires the user having access to their other device, be in Android or iOS, but it also means no passwords, as long as they're signed into one device, they can authorize the same to happen on another.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be creating a custom API and posting credentials from both platforms to that API.

Comment: The actual intention is to allow a user to automatically authorize in e.g. the Android app if he/she already authorized on my iOS app. Obviously I can't just ask the user to enter login/email and autofill the password for him. The problem is I can't asocciate the new Android user with existing iOS user until after he/she actually authorizes on Android.